# Nested REST API route validation

Tags: php, laravel, rest, validation, coding-style

I have some routes like these:

```
GET /post/1/comment/1
PUT /post/1/comment/1
POST /post/1/comment/1/reply
```

Validation for post_id & comment_id for each API in controllers will create a lot of duplicate code.

For example:

**CommentsController**

```
function getInfo($postId, $commentId)
{
    // validate postId
    // validate commentId
    // find & return Comment
}

function update(UpdateRequest $request, $postId, $commentId)
{
    // validate postId
    // validate commentId
    // update Comment
}

function reply(CreateReplyRequest $request, $postId, $commentId)
{
    // validate postId
    // validate commentId
    // create reply for Comment
}
```

What should be done to reduce code duplication here? What are the best practices?

**UPDATE 1:**

Its in Lumen, so can't use Route Model Binding? Is route model binding supposed to have some performance issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a Middleware and validate data in it.

Then in your controller only return the resources you want.

Routes :

```
/**
 * Authentification & validation middleware API Version 1
 **/
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth.api.v1']], function()
{
   Route::get('infos/{postId}/{commentId}', '...Controller@getInfo');
   [...]
});
```

In your middleware :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware\API\V1;

use Closure;
use Validator;
use Input;
use Log;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request and format data request
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Validating $request
        $rules = [
            'data' => ['required'],
            [...]
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            Log::debug($validator->messages());
            abort(403, 'Forbidden');
        }

        [...]

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

In your Controller :

```
function getInfo($postId, $commentId)
{
    // find & return Comment
}
```

Comment: Nice. But since its a query based validation, is there any way in an OOP style that I can use the retrived object in my controller?

Comment: Yes, you can add parameters to the request beofre the end of the middleware : $request->request->add([myObject' => $object]); (then you can get it from the controller like this : "$request->myObject"

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding) this will validate the model id and give you the corresponding comment or post model.

This way you extract the validation of the model id's.

I don't now how your reply model work, but i guess its a message with a parent_message_id attribute. You can use the same POST endpoint as comment `POST /post/1/comment`, add an optional parameter:

`'parent_message_id' => 'nullable|exists:comments,parent_message_id'`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that its LUMEN, and in Lumen route model binding is not available. May be for some performance boost.